# Referring to female college age students while writing a novel

Tags: word-choice, writing, gender

I am trying to write a novel. I want to write in a manner that will be respectful toward gender.

I have not yet figured out how to refer to female college-age characters quickly and smoothly without just calling them girls. "Young ladies" sounds respectful but awkward especially when used repeatedly.

For example, the main character might walk down a busy path across the college campus and see many female peers along the way. I need a way to be able to refer to these peers and describe them as they are observed in passing.

Can I just say "A **girl** with long black hair walked by staring with wide eyes. Behind her, another **girl** slowly lowered her phone from her ear, and snapped a photo."

or would I need to say "A **young woman** with long black hair walked by staring with wide eyes. Behind her, another **young woman** slowly lowered her phone from her ear, and snapped a photo."

Do you see how it will get cumbersome? My novel is intended to be fantasy and humorous at times. I need to keep it informal sounding.

Help?

Comment: I sympathize with your plight, but I suspect the people whom you think will be offended by *girl* will not be part of your audience. You will not lose those readers by using the word *girl*. Does that help?

Comment: Call the "girls" students, undergrads, classmates, group of guys (*guys* is used for both sexes) Would you say *boys* if it was the other way round? *A **female student** with long black hair looked at me and smiled back*.... *another lowered **her** phone, and snapped a photo*

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to rely on pronouns. That's controversial in other ways, but might solve your particular problem

> A passing student stared, then tossed her long black hair in
> astonishment. Another slowly lowered her phone from her ear to snap a
> photo.

If this doesn't work I would expect "woman" or "young woman" rather than "girl".

Your choice may also depend on your intended audience. Some readers will expect more formality and respectful address than others.

Answer (score 0):

How about you introduce the whole group using 'young ladies' and then, mention each one using 'One of them... Another one..., Behind her, a tall blonde..., etc.?
I have no idea how or whether this might work at all, though.'

Answer (score 0):

They're "co-eds".  Yes, it's archaic and anachronistic, but it's the best you can do in a genderless language.